# Widget Question: Comparing multiple pairs on same % scale

Tags: widget, tradingview-api

i hope i formulated my question right.

I want to display this chart :
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/EZn59q0h/?symbol=CRYPTOCAP%3AUSDT.D

on my wordpress website, iframe is not working and when i use the widgets from the Tradingview, they are not showing the compared pairs but only the main symbol.

Is there any way?

Thank you for your help

i asked chatgpt but:

```
"<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_49079"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Cryptocurrency Market Cap chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": false, // set to false to disable autosizing
  "symbols": [
    {
      "symbol": "CRYPTOCAP:USDT.D", // USDT.D for USDT Dominance
      "interval": "1", // change to your desired interval
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "dark", // set to "dark" for dark theme
      "style": "8", // change to your desired style number
      "locale": "en",
    },
    {
      "symbol": "BINANCE:BTCUSDT", // Replace with the desired futures USDT pairs from Binance
      "interval": "1", // change to your desired interval
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "dark", // set to "dark" for dark theme
      "style": "8", // change to your desired style number
      "locale": "en",
    },
    {
      "symbol": "BINANCE:ETHUSDT", // Replace with the desired futures USDT pairs from Binance
      "interval": "1", // change to your desired interval
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "dark", // set to "dark" for dark theme
      "style": "8", // change to your desired style number
      "locale": "en",
    }
  ],
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "hide_legend": true,
  "withdateranges": true,
  "hide_side_toolbar": false,
  "show_popup_button": true,
  "popup_width": "960",
  "popup_height": "640",
  "container_id": "tradingview_49079"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
"
```

is also not working.